# iphone Reporting Score to Game Center

Tags: iphone, game-center

When reporting scores to Game Center, if the method `-reportScoreWithCompletionHandler` encounters an error does that necessarily imply the score was not posted? Or are there occasions where the score can be posted but an error was encountered? I'd like to have this clear so that my handling block (which conditions on `error` being nil or not) can handle this better.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a problem with the posting -> you get an error. If there is no problem -> no error. I'm sure it does imply.

Comment: This is what I would assume, yes. I worried that I might have been getting both scores reporting and an error but I can't reproduce this easily. Then I wondered that this "error if and only if not posted" might only be an "if".